# How to selecting data dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, multi-index

I have dataframe like this:

```
   Tahun  Jan   Feb     Mar     Apr     Mei     Jun     Jul     Ags     Sep     Okt     Nov     Des
0  2020   0.39  0.28    0.10    0.08    0.07    0.18    -0.10   -0.05   -0.05   0.07    0.28    0.45
1  2021   0.26  0.10    0.08    0.13    0.32    -0.16   0.08    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

This is how df.head() looks like
[image]

df.index show and df.columns

[image]

df.to_dict() show

[image]

I expect output like  this:

```
Tahun   2021
Jul     0.08
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

but I dont know how to do, I only know how to take the value of 0.08. I did this:

```
for i in df.iloc[-1][::-1]:
    if i == '0.00':
        continue
    else:
        break
print(i)
```

any one have idea? thanks

Comment: Could you explain what are the conditions that you need in order to get to this expected output please?

Comment: @Odhian actually, I dont want take it manually. So, I want to select the current value that != 0.00 which on July 2021

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive that by taking the `Tahun` as index and selecting the relevant column i.e.`Jul` from the data. Lastly, take a `transpose` of the dataframe.

The sample is recreated and produced to adapt:

```
import pandas as pd
s=pd.DataFrame({
    'Tahun':[2020,2021],
    'Jan':[1,2],
    'Jul':[2,3]})

s.set_index('Tahun')[['Jul']].T
```

Comment: actually, I dont want take it manually. So, I want to select the current value that != 0.00 which on July 2021